# typologies PDE in CFD applications

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, parabolic-pde

I am studying PDE, their typologies and their characteristic for the use in CFD. This question is a follow up of [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562779/question-about-hyperbolic-pde). I am reading [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562779/question-about-hyperbolic-pde), and several question raised to my mind (pg. 31):

1. Regarding the Hyperbolic PDE: I understood that for the D'Alambert Eq. the region of the initial condition $[x_{i}-t_{i},x_{i}+t_{i}]$ that impacts the solution at $P(x_i,t_i)$, this because of the characteristic directions. It is difficult to understand why  the solution in a point P depends on the whole area of the domain of dependence and not only from $[x_{i}-t_{i},x_{i}+t_{i}]$.
2. For the Parabolic case: Given the Eq.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \tag{1}$

With intial condition $u=sin(\pi x)$ and boundary condition $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$ Eq. (1) the solution  is:

$u(x,t)=sin(\pi x)exp(-\pi^2 t) \tag{2}$

So there is an exponential decay in time. The book says that the solution "march forward in time and diffuse in space." I don't understand the meaning of this phrase. How is the "marching" linked with the exponential decay in time? What does it mean that "diffuses" in space?

3. Regarding the Elliptic one: Since the missing of the variable t in the PDE, would I  not have a solution that variates in time, but only values that variates in space?

Thanks in advance

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562779/question-about-hyperbolic-pde) Fletcher, Clive A. J. (1998). Computational Techniques for Fluid Dynamics 1 .